# Output custom error message instead of default php error message

Tags: php

I am using the PHP copy function in part of my program, where the parameters of the function depend on user input. I am trying to avoid the default php error message if they include a path that the function cannot use, and output a custom message like shown below. I am new to handling errors/ exceptions. I am still getting the php default error message instead of the custom 'Path was incorrect!' using the method below.

What I tried:

```
try{
    copy($webImagePath, $destinationPath);
 }
 catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Path was incorrect!';
 }
```

Comment: You could create your own error handler with `set_error_handler`  and use functions like `strpos`, `str_replace` to change around your errors.. It's a little work, but it goes along way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider `set_error_handler`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Example:

```
set_error_handler("someFunction");

function someFunction($errno, $errstr) {
    output details and information
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should have thrown an Exception with custom message you wished to display.
You can either suppress the default PHP error message for individual statements by preceding them with an '@' symbol. Or you might change error_reporting level per page( check this link for more details:http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Also check the folowing code snippet

```
$file='example.txt';          //replace the file name with your URL
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';
try{
  $ret=@copy($file, $newfile);
  if (!$ret){
    throw new Exception("File path doesn't exist..");
  }
}
catch(Exception $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```